# Getting Negative Expiry when Using Fog AWS S3 & Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fog

I'm attempting to generate a signed url for a file in S3 using [Fog](https://github.com/fog/fog); however, the url that get's returned always returns a negative expiry which causes the url to `400`.

```
connection = Fog::Storage.new(
  region: 'us-west-1',
  provider: 'AWS',
  aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'],
  aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY']
)
bucket = connection.directories.get(BUCKET)
file = 'test.jpg'
p file_url = bucket.files.get_https_url("uploads/#{file}", 300)
```

Generated URL:

```
https://account.s3-us-west-x.amazonaws.com/files/test.doc?X-Amz-Expires=-1443648781&X-Amz-Date=20150930T213801Z&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AAAVA***FA/20150930/us-west-x/s3/aws4_request&X
-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=e31663f9b2470e***215825d585b14c37e
```

Am I missing something here? Why is the generated url giving me a negative expiration (`X-Amz-Expires`)?

Comment: is time on your system configured correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `expires` argument appears to be expecting the absolute expiration time in unix epoch time... not the number of seconds from now.

If true, then "300" would be an expiration time of "1970-01-01 00:05:00 UTC" which was, I'm guessing, 1443648781 seconds in the past, at the time when you generated that signed URL.

The signature you're generating is AWS Signature V4, and in the URL itself, the expiration time will be shown in seconds from now... but the old AWS Signature V2 expected an absolute epoch time, so based on the legacy behavior, it would make sense if the library still expected epoch time as the argument regardless of the signature version in use... and did the subtraction when building the url... but it seems a little silly for such a glaringly invalid value to be blindly accepted by the library.

Comment: This isn't clearly document anywhere either. The closest place is here: https://github.com/fog/fog-aws/blob/master/lib/fog/aws/requests/storage/get_object_https_url.rb#L15

Comment: Also this: https://github.com/fog/fog-aws/blob/69e4795fe8abaedfa825157748a1f0693d03ea3a/lib/fog/aws/storage.rb#L160

Comment: You can apply an option `{aws_signature_version: 2}` to force `AWS::Storage` or `Fog::Storage` to the older version 2

Answer (score 0):

Future searchers:

```
# url that expires in 5 minutes
p file_url = bucket.files.get_https_url("uploads/#{file}", Time.now + (5 * 60))
```